# Babel's TypeScript parsing is not consistent

Tags: angular, babeljs

I tried the following Angular component code (in TypeScript) in [ASTExplorer](https://astexplorer.net/) by choosing `babylon7-7.0.0-beta.12` and `babelv7-7.0.0-alpha.12` and it parses, transforms and produces the exact output:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  data: [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4',
    'Item 5'
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

However, when I try to parse and transform the same code with same version of Babel and Babylon using Babel's `transformFileSync` API, I get the following error:

```
This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'decorators, decorators2' (3:0)
  1 | import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  2 | 
> 3 | @Component({
    | ^
```

So, I passed the following plugins to the API (as there were more errors):

```
plugins: [
            ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
            ['transform-typescript'],
            ['transform-class-properties']
]
```

But, this produces an output which is very different from the input code:

```
var _dec, _class;

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export let ListComponent = (_dec = Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
}), _dec(_class = class ListComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}) || _class);
```

Would appreciate your help on identifying the root cause so that I am able to parse Angular TypeScript code and build my further transformation logic.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is, does the output code not work? How do you expect it to be different?

Comment: Basically, I want to know what versions of Babel, Babylon, and related plugins that I need to use so that the transformFileSync API produces the same output that ASTExplorer produces - https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/8a44bb7a5bca7db9ddabfe3b0818747e/180dfc8525927cbb455c708a5da0f79fa901168b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same output as the input, don't use any `transform` plugins, just `babel-plugin-syntax-typescript` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a tonne Peter! I switched to syntax- version of the plugins and it is working as expected.

Comment: No problem. The `transform` plugins emit JavaScript, which doesn't (yet) have class properties, decorators, etc.