# This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'exportDefaultFrom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, jscodeshift

`This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'exportDefaultFrom'`

I am getting the above error while trying to move the entire application from react `v15.6`to `v16.2`, by using the migration tool from facebook like `jscodeshift`.

Comment: It is a known issue https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift/issues/252

Comment: amazing what you can find by simply using a search engine on the exact title of the question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel's TypeScript parsing is not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920528/babels-typescript-parsing-is-not-consistent)

Answer (score 2):

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from (https://git.io/vb4yH) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.

```
const parser = require('./src/parser');
const jscodeshift = require('jscodeshift').withParser(parser);
```

./src/parser:

```
'use strict';

const babylon = require('babylon');

// These are the options that were the default of the Babel5 parse function
// see https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/5.x/packages/babel/src/api/node.js#L81

const options = {
  sourceType: 'module',
  allowHashBang: true,
  ecmaVersion: Infinity,
  allowImportExportEverywhere: true,
  allowReturnOutsideFunction: true,
  plugins: [
    'estree',
    'jsx',
    'asyncGenerators',
    'classProperties',
    'doExpressions',
    'exportExtensions',
    'functionBind',
    'functionSent',
    'objectRestSpread',
    'dynamicImport',
    'nullishCoalescingOperator',
    'optionalChaining',
    'exportDefaultFrom'
  ],
};

/**
 * Wrapper to set default options
 */
exports.parse = function parse (code) {
  return babylon.parse(code, options);
};
```

Please add the 'exportDefaultFrom' into plugins.