# ESlint Parser error: "exportDefaultFrom" plugin required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

While running ESLint on my project, I encountered the following error:

> error  Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling the
> parser plugin: "exportDefaultFrom".

I've been trying to find the appropriate parser plugin for this syntax, but I'm having trouble locating it. It seems related to the import/export rule. Can someone guide me on how to resolve this issue? Is there a specific plugin I need to install or a configuration change I should make?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888505/this-experimental-syntax-requires-enabling-the-parser-plugin-exportdefaultfrom ?